# "kill -l" only returns ZERR

Tags: zsh, kill

While trying to send `SIGQUIT` I got this:

```
$ kill -s QUIT 4341      
kill: unknown signal: SIGQUIT
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

And I was very surprised to see this:

```
$ kill -l
ZERR
```

So, somehow `kill` doesn't know all signal names. This is Ubuntu artful (yeah time to upgrade it, but it's another issue)

Obviously I sent `SIGQUIT` just by using a number `3`, but, what could cause `kill` to forget the signal names?

UPD: this is zsh.

```
$ type kill     
kill is a shell builtin                
$ echo $ZSH_VERSION $ZSH_PATCHLEVEL                                                             
5.0.2 1.5778
```

I verified that `/bin/kill` works fine, so must be something zsh-specific..

Comment: this is probably going to require `strace` or looking through the source code for `kill` as it's probably something at the system call level of horkage...

Comment: For me it looks like you're in some weird shell and running it's builtin `kill` command. Check your `echo $SHELL` ? `/bin/kill -l` vs `kill -l` ?

Comment: Thanks @Alexander you're right, `/bin/kill` works fine

Comment: This isn't "wierd" and pretty much _all_ job control shells have built-in `kill` commands, a requisite for being able to kill jobs.

Comment: IIRC, the script that was used to retrieve the signal list at build time got broken after some upgrade of gcc (cpp). You probably have an older version of zsh built with a newer gcc, try upgrading zsh or build it with an older gcc. There was a similar problem with errnos. Other shells like pdksh were affected by the change in gcc behaviour in that regard.

Comment: See https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg00212.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is almost certainly `zsh`, and you probably have `kill` defined as an alias or a function (check with `type kill`).

But I'm still not able to reproduce your case:

```
zsh$ kill -l 30
PWR
zsh$ kill -l 31
SYS
zsh$ kill -l 32
32
zsh$ kill -l -96
32
```

`32` is the index of `"ZERR"` in the `zsh`'s signal names table, but, as seen, (at least on my system) it's correctly clamped to the max signal number (`31`).

Please update your question with the version of your `zsh` (`echo $ZSH_VERSION $ZSH_PATCHLEVEL`) and of your OS (`uname -a`). I guess it was one of those bad patches that fester in distribution ports (quick "fixes" not vetted by the upstream developers).

**Update:**

Try installing the `zsh` package from the artful [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/zsh) (version 5.2.5) or recompiling a recent version of `zsh` from source.

The problem was really caused by a bug in older versions of `zsh` -- the linemarkers generated by `gcc`/`cpp` (the `# lnum_of_definition "header.h" 3 4` lines added before the expansions of macros defined in the system headers), were confusing the [`signames2.awk`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/signames2.awk) script used to generate the list of signals and numbers. Notice instead of fixing that script, they simply prevented the generation of linemarkers with the `-P` option of `cpp` in recent version of `zsh`.

See [here](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg00212.html). Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas for the hint -- I had looked at those `awk` scripts, but my lack of flair made me not consider them as culprits, since they weren't changed in ages.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. The `$ZSH_VERSION $ZSH_PATCHLEVEL` are `5.0.2 1.5778`. And yeah, it's definitely zsh-specific problem, thanks.

Comment: The clue here is that 32 is _not_ the index of `ZERR`.  Another clue is that `kill -l 30` yielded `USR1` when I just typed it.  Think about the build-time mechanism that makes both of those the case.

Answer (score 3):

This has to be a problem with how your zsh executable was built. The list of signals is determined at compile time from the operating system. The “fake signal” `ZERR`, which represents exits due to an error rather than due to a signal, is added at the end of the list. In your build, somehow, the list of signals from the OS is empty.

[Stéphane Chazelas identified a likely culprit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477605/kill-l-only-returns-zerr#comment873146_477605), which is a [now-fixed incompatibility of the build scripts with recent versions of the GCC compiler](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg00212.html). If you just build a more recent version of zsh, the problem should be resolved. But note that Ubuntu artful comes with zsh 5.2, which is more recent than your version. Even the previous long-time support release of Ubuntu has 5.1.1. So there's no reason to keep your own build unless you need this older version for compatibility testing. If you absolutely need to keep this older version, build it with an older version of GCC.